# Prove by induction a property of the alternating sum of odd integers.

Tags: calculus

The Question goes like this:
"Prove, by induction, that the sum $\sum_{k=1}^{2n} (- 1)^k (2k + 1)$ is proportional to n, and find the
constant of proportionality." From Apostol, Calculus, Volume 1.

The value of $\sum_{k=1}^{2n}(- 1)^k (2k + 1)$ is $2n$, that is $\sum_{k=1}^{2n}(- 1)^k (2k + 1)=2n$. So proportionality constant is $2$.

While proving by induction, I came across a solution online:

> Assume that the formula holds for some $n = m \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$. Then,
> $$\sum_{k=1}^{2m}(- 1)^k (2k + 1) = 2m \Longrightarrow\sum_{k=0}^{2(m+1)}(- 1)^k (2k + 1)= 2m-(2(2m+1)+1)+(2(2m+2)+2)=2(m+1)$$
> Hence Proved"

Could you please elaborate how $2m-(2(2m+1)+1)+(2(2m+2)+1)$ came to be?

Comment: The terms of the sum when $k=2m+1$ and $k=2m+2$ have just been added to both sides.

Comment: The limit should be $k=1$ not $k=0$ in the displayed formula.